# Mongodb connection failed using mongoclient in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I've been trying to connect to my local mongodb using mongodb NPM Package. This is my code:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("index");
});

router.post("/submit", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/", (err,client) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      console.log('db connected');
      client.db('login').collection('users').insertOne(req.body);
    }
  })

  res.send("form submitted");
});

module.exports = router;
```

the console doesn't show any error nor connects to db.

Comment: Do you ever actually make a request? You respond before the connection can even be made, how are you determining it isn't? Give a [mre].

Comment: You are running `MongoClient.connect` inside every post request. This can be done outside of your route handlers one time straight after you import the `MongoClient` module. To make matters worse you are returning the response `res.send("form submitted");` before your asynchronous `connect` and `insertOne` have a chance to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is not a production ready code but to answer your question, try the code below.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("index");
});

router.post("/submit", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/", (err,client) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send("mongodb Error");
    }else{
      console.log('db connected');
      client.db('login').collection('users').insertOne(req.body);
      return res.status(200).send("form submitted");
    }
  })
});

module.exports = router;
```